# Value of dropdown -> textbox expand

Tags: javascript, html, css

the basic idea is to have three options

1. email #1 from database
2. email #2 from database
3. new email

When user would choose #3, a textbox would expand on bottom of dropdown so entering new email would be accessible.

Have you seen something like this anywhere? Any samples/techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this requires is having a form field whose initial properties are `style="display:none"`, then showing it if the third option is chosen.

Here's the poor man's version:

```
<select onchange="displayEmail(this)">
   <!-- Put your items here -->
</select>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="display: none;" />
```

JS:

```
function displayEmail(element) {
    if(element.selectedIndex==2) {
        document.getElementById('email').style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I want! If that's not too much to ask: how to close textbox when user changes back to already existing entries in dropdown?

Comment: if(element.selectedIndex!=2) {
        document.getElementById('email').style.display="none"
    }

Comment: I changed `<input type="test` to `<input type="text"` :)

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo.